# PostgreSQL Hstore field - key contains string

Tags: sql, django, postgresql

I am using Hstore data in my PostgreSQL database with my Django application.
Keys for hstore field are generated through the process and contain a 10 digit number. Values are decimal numbers.

In my SQL Query I do the following to summarize entries for a particular key:

```
SELECT
    SUM((entries->'0123456789')::numeric)
FROM
    public.appname_model
WHERE
    entries ? '0123456789';
```

Is it possible to summarize all hsore entries data that would contain first 8 digits, something like:
`entries ? '01234567%';`

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have multiple rows and multiple values in each `entries` column, expand `entries` using `each()` and `sum()` with a `regex`:

```
with appname_model (id, entries) as (
 values (1, '01234=>1,01235=>2,01111=>3'::hstore),
        (2, '01234=>4,01235=>5,01111=>6'::hstore)
)
select sum(e.v::numeric)
  from appname_model
       cross join lateral each(entries) as e(k,v)
 where k ~ '^0123'
        
;
 sum 
-----
  12
(1 row)
```